# Does Spark distributes dataframe across nodes internally?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use Spark for processing csv file on cluster. I want to understand if I need to explicitly read the file on each of the worker nodes to do the processing in parallel or will the driver node read the file and distribute the data across cluster for processing internally? (I am working with Spark 2.3.2 and Python)

**I know RDD's can be parallelized using SparkContext.parallelize() but what in case of Spark DataFrames?**

```
if __name__=="__main__":
     spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('myApp').getOrCreate()
     df=spark.read.csv('dataFile.csv',header=True)
     df=df.filter("date>'2010-12-01' AND date<='2010-12-02' AND town=='Madrid'")
```

**So if I am running the above code on cluster, will the entire operation be done by driver node or will it distribute df across cluster and each worker perform processing on its data partition?**

Comment: I believe it is done by the worker, you can check the spark UI to confirm that

Comment: @dtheo so how does the worker receive it's data partition? Does the driver send it or is it stored in workers when we do read.csv itself?

Answer (score 12):

To be strict, if you run the above code it will not read or process any data. DataFrames are basically an abstraction implemented on top of RDDs. As with RDDs, you have to distinguish *transformations* and *actions*. As your code only consists of one `filter(...)` transformation, noting will happen in terms of readind or processing of data. Spark will only create the DataFrame which is an execution plan. You have to perform an action like `count()` or `write.csv(...)` to actually trigger processing of the CSV file.

If you do so, the data will then be read and processed by 1..n worker nodes. It is never read or processed by the driver node. How many or your worker nodes are actually involved depends -- in your code -- on the number of partitions of your source file. Each partition of the source file can be processed in parallel by one worker node. In your example it is probably a single CSV file, so when you call `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` after you read the file, it should return `1`. Hence, only one worker node will read the data. The same is true if you check the number of partitions after your `filter(...)` operation.

Here are two ways of how the processing of your single CSV file can be parallelized:

1. You can manually repartition your source DataFrame by calling `df.repartition(n)` with `n` the number of partitions you want to have. But -- and this is a significant but -- this means that all data is potentially send over the network (aka shuffle)!
2. You perform aggregations or joins on the DataFrame. These operations *have* to trigger a shuffle. Spark then uses the number of partitions specified in `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`(default: 200) to partition the resulting DataFrame.

Comment: thanks for the verbose description, it helps to clear some of my doubts @effemm. The code snippet I provided is just a partial part of my program. But like you mentioned I tried to do df.rdd.getNumPartitions() by running it on my local and it gives me 4 instead of 1 like you specified. Is it because SPARK is treating my 2cores (4logical processors) as individual nodes for distribution?